# Big inputs in command prompt

Tags: c++, visual-c++, input, command-prompt

I want to give a big input in command prompt i.e.

```
100 100
437 1
68 0
319 0
565 0
307 1
512 0
493 0
30 0
557 0
367 0
547 1
263 0
481 0
78 0
492 1
56 1
81 0
154 0
503 1
375 0
152 0
401 0
226 0
482 0
264 0
52 0
9 0
145 0
72 0
293 0
15 0
42 1
305 0
34 0
509 0
156 0
321 0
437 0
510 1
449 0
79 0
492 0
191 0
354 1
529 0
315 0
384 0
371 0
100 0
480 0
408 0
221 0
286 0
551 0
106 0
123 0
549 0
183 1
428 0
435 0
370 0
46 0
289 0
246 0
414 1
159 0
442 0
286 0
21 0
119 0
263 0
572 0
334 0
96 0
307 0
323 0
554 1
487 0
455 1
399 0
559 0
276 0
357 1
586 0
346 0
240 1
492 0
63 0
262 0
489 0
124 1
526 0
350 1
243 0
35 0
292 0
418 0
364 1
41 1
519 0
```

This is the part of my code that takes the input :

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a >> b;
        A.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, bool>(a, b));
        total += a;
        if (b == 1)
            totalI++;
    }
```

I can obviously just type it all but there must be a shorter way and I want to know what it is. Or is there some other tool / IDE I can use. I am using Visual Studio 2015 (Community)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just redirect input to the program.

```
C:\> my_litte_program <mydata.txt
```

---

To run the program that way from within Visual Studio 2015, just configure it in the project's debug options:

[image]

This works also for running without debugging, e.g. via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: I would have answered that too, but then the problem is that you cannot debug your program from within your IDE.  Also, this is mentioned in my answer, so it does not add anything.

Comment: To run the program this way from within Visual Studio you can probably configure it in the debug options. But it takes some time for me to test that, because VS takes a heck of a long time starting up here.

Comment: @MikeNakis: I don't like your answer of passing in a filename and opening a file. It's needlessly complicated and it gets even more complicated if one wants to do it properly for non-ASCII filenames. Regarding "cannot debug", that's just nonsense.

Comment: Visual studio may have changed since the last time I used it, so it may be possible to configure it to redirect the console in the debug options, but last time I tried (years ago) there was no such option, so you had to do it my way.  A verification that this is in fact now possible would be useful.

Comment: @MikeNakis: I've used Visual Studio since the early 16-bit days. You're talking nonsense. I'm sorry.

Comment: I have used Visual Studio since the mid-nineties and I still don't find it a reason to insult people about it.

Comment: @MikeNakis: *ad hominem* argumentation just says you **know** that  you're wrong, and that you're not nice.

Comment: Visual Studio express has an option called "command line". Try adding the redirection to it.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: Please give a concrete example of what you mean. Details.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Note that even if Visual Studio did not offer this option (which it always has, according to what I remember, but I honestly don't recall the situation before 2005), you could still attach the debugger to the process after the program has been started from the command line, possibly also using the `DebugBreak` function. The point is, there are a lot of ways to debug the program in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `cin`; instead, use a stream declared by you.  Say, `myin`.

Put all that "big inputs" of yours in a text file, say, `myBigInputs.txt`

Make the `main()` function of your program accept an argument, which is going to be a filename.  Use that filename to open `myin` with.  Edit your launch configuration and make it so that when you launch your program from within your IDE, the argument `myBigInputs.txt` is passed to it.

You can also make the argument to your program optional.  If you detect that no argument was passed, then just do `myin = cin;` in which case your program will work exactly as previously.  Then, you will also be able to run your program as follows:  `myprogram < myBigInput.txt`

Comment: I really fail to see what this accomplishes, considering that you can just do `myprogram.exe < myBigInputs.txt`. It seems to add a lot of complexity for nothing.

Comment: @ChristianHackl read the comments under "Cheers and hth"'s answer for an explanation of why I answered that.

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio. Load the project. Go to Debug ... Properties ... Configuration Properties ... Debugging

That gives you all the options for setting up the command line. Add "< data.txt" as "command argument"